# How can I calculate total days past due between billing events?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am dealing with a dataframe with subscription events partitioned by username, subscription status, and relative timestamps. For each of the dates, there are changes in time when the subscription becomes past due and renews as such:

| username | subscription_events_name | subscription_events_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | subscription_charged_unsuccess | 2021-01-08 |
| A | subscription_past_due | 2021-01-08 |
| A | subscription_past_due | 2021-01-15 |
| A | subscription_charged_successfully | 2021-01-16 |
| A | subscription_renew | 2021-01-16 |

Say a customer enters past due status, and 15 days later their subscription is billed in full and they enter an active status. I want to store this value in a new column for `days_past_due`:

| username | subscription_events_name | subscription_events_timestamp | days_past_due |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | subscription_charged_unsuccess | 2021-01-08 | 0 |
| A | subscription_past_due | 2021-01-08 | 0 |
| A | subscription_past_due | 2021-01-15 | 7 |
| A | subscription_charged_successfully | 2021-01-16 | 0 |
| A | subscription_renew | 2021-01-16 | 0 |

I created an expanding window for this, but it only counts values of `subscription_events_name`. How can I modify this code or produce new code to achieve this?

```
df['days_past_due'] = df.groupby([
'username', 
'subscription_events_name')[['subscription_events_timestamp']].transform(lambda x: x.expanding().count())
df.sort_values(by=['subscription_events_timestamp'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use another approach, I propose this one:

1. Convert to `datetime` the `subscription_events_timestamp` column.

   ```
   df['subscription_events_timestamp'] = df['subscription_events_timestamp'].apply(lambda date: pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y-%m-%d'))
   ```
2. Using [`.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html?highlight=diff#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff) method, you can get the difference between the current date and the date immediately below, once you get the difference, you can use `dt.days` to express it as days.

   ```
   df['days_past_due'] = df.groupby(['username', 'subscription_events_name'])['subscription_events_timestamp'].diff().dt.days
   ```
3. Using [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html?highlight=fillna#pandas.Series.fillna) method you can replace the NaN values got in the previous step by `0`

   ```
   df['days_past_due'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
   ```

Output:

|  | username | subscription_events_name | subscription_events_timestamp | days_past_due |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | subscription_charged_unsuccess | 2021-01-08 | 0.0 |
| 1 | A | subscription_past_due | 2021-01-08 | 0.0 |
| 2 | A | subscription_past_due | 2021-01-15 | 7.0 |
| 3 | A | subscription_charged_successfully | 2021-01-16 | 0.0 |
| 4 | A | subscription_renew | 2021-01-16 | 0.0 |